# Check if unit vector lies in between two other unit vectors using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, vector, between

I've got a two unit vectors (one almost perpendicular to the other). How can I check using matlab if any other unit vector I have lies between these two unit vectors?

I have tried sing the dot product, but that gives a false positive when the third unit vector is within the same angle but on the other side of it.

Thanks

Comment: It's better to give examples of data, and your attempts.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have two unit vectors **a** and **b**, just like your **xyz** axes ( which is a specific case where the vectors **x=a** and **y=b** are perpendicular and nothing happens in **z**) specify quadrants:

**+a+b**,  **-a+b**,  **-a-b**, **+a-b**.

Now I assume that by "lies between these two unit vectors" you mean quadrant +a+b?

If so: you can check this by calculating the projection of your test vector lets say c on vectors **a** and **b**:

projection_ConB = **c** * **b**' and similarly **c** * **a'**. Which are indeed the dot products.

Now the signs of both these projections will tell you in what quadrant defined by a and b vector c is in.

Now I'm not sure if there is a build-in function for this but it should be easy enough to make your own function!

Answer (score 0):

The dot product should work just fine.  If `a` and `b` define the region and `c` is the vector to test, then

```
if dot(a,b) < dot(a,c) && dot(a,b) < dot(b,c)
```

If your vectors aren't actually unit vectors, you'll need to include the lengths in the test.

```
if norm(c) * dot(a,b) < norm(b) * dot(a,c) && norm(c) * dot(a,b) < norm(a) * dot(b,c)
```